# Property 'forEach' does not exist on type XXX in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I want to generate a list of table rows by using `forEach()` in Typescript and React. I get `Property 'forEach' does not exist on type` when using the code below. Does anyone know how to fix this? Shouldn't I be able to use forEach() on persons as it is an array of PersonInterfaces?

```
interface PersonList {
  [index: number]: PersonInterface
}

interface PersonInterface {
  name: string, 
  age: number
}

const persons:PersonList = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    age: 25,
  }, {
    name: 'Jill',
    age: 28,
  }
];

export default function Table() {
  return (
    <table>
      {
        persons.forEach(person => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{person.name}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })
        }
    </table>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:-

```
interface Person {
  name: string, 
  age: number
}

const persons:Person[] = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    age: 25,
  }, {
    name: 'Jill',
    age: 28,
  }
];

export default function Table() {
  return (
    <table>
      {
        persons.forEach(person => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{person.name}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })
        }
    </table>
  );
}
```

Your `persons` variable was not a valid array object. You have sets its type to `PersonList` which itself is essentially a type. That's why you're getting `Property 'forEach' doesn't exist on type`.

One more thing, `forEach` doesn't return a new array. Use `map` here instead of `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

As well as your typing problem, I'm guessing you want to use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
import React from 'react'

interface PersonInterface {
  name: string
  age: number
}

const persons: PersonInterface[] = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    age: 25,
  },
  {
    name: 'Jill',
    age: 28,
  },
]

const Table = () => {
  return (
    <table>
      {persons.map(person => (
        <tr>
          <td>{person.name}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  )
}

export default Table
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is a method from JS Class `Array`, if you want to use it in a custom Class, it should inherit from `Array` or just be one (`persons:Person[]`), as suggested by Lakshya.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Could be a better answer if you can give a code snippet for inheriting an `Array`.